# I am facing issue when converting json to dart, below is the json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[IN this you can find the error when json is converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdSM1.png)When i convert the below json to dart using https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ ,it says 'The Dart code generated is invalid'.I am using future builder to display the response in user-interface.
when i comment out the 'state' class the error goes but no response is shown.

```
      {
                  "result": {
                      "userDetails": {
                          "digilockerid": "...digilockerid...",
                          "name": "...name...",
                          "dob": "...dob...",
                          "gender": "...M/F/T...",
                          "eaadhaar": "...Y or N as per availability..."
                      },
                      "files": [{
                          "name": "Aadhaar Card",
                          "type": "file",
                          "size": "",
                          "date": "...date...",
                          "parent": "",
                          "mime": [
                              "application/pdf",
                              "application/xml",
                              "application/json"
                          ],
                          "doctype": "...5 letter DOC key...",
                          "description": "...Description...",
                          "issuerid": "...issuer id...",
                          "issuer": "...issuer name...",
                          "id": "...unique file ID..."
                      }],
                      "eAadhaar": {
                          "name": "...name...",
                          "dob": "...date of birth...",
                          "uid":"...uid...",
                          "gender": "...gender...",
                          "x509Data": {
                              "validAadhaarDSC": "...is eaadhaar certificate valid or not (yes/no)..."
                          },
                          "address": "...address",
                          "photo": "...link to photo as on eaadhaar...",
                          "splitAddress": {
                              "district": [
                                  "...district name..."
                              ],
                              "state": [
                                  [
                                      "...state name...",
                                      "...2 digit state code..."
                                  ]
                              ],
                              "city": [
                                  "...city name..."
                              ],
                              "pincode": "...pincode...",
                              "country": [
                                  "...2 digit ISO country name...",
                                  "...3 digit ISO country name...",
                                  "...country name..."
                              ],
                              "addressLine": "...address..."
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
```

Comment: Are you using null safety?

Comment: noo ,this isnt related to null safety.This issue is seen when converting json to object online

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be right for you, but it worked, I changed this:

```
"state": [
      [
           "...state name...",
           "...2 digit state code..."
                                  ]
                              ]
```

To this:

```
"state": [
             "...state name...",
             "...2 digit state code..."
             ]
```

And it's not showing the invalid dart code message

Comment: yea the error was gone,bt im nt getting the response json